# How can I accomplish ThreadPool.Join?

Tags: multithreading, .net-3.5, windows-services, threadpool

I am writing a windows service that uses `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`.  Each thread is a short-lived task.

When the service is stopped, I need to make sure that all the threads that are currently executing complete.  Is there some way of waiting until the queue clears itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create an event (e.g. `ManualResetEvent`) in each thread, and keep it in a synchronised list (using the `lock` construct).  Set the event or remove it from the list when the task is finished.

When you want to join, you can use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall.aspx)) to wait for all the events to be signalled.

It's a hack, but I can't see how to reduce it to anything simpler!

---

Edit: additionally, you could ensure that no new events get posted, then wait a couple of seconds.  If they are indeed short-lived, you'll have no problem.  Even simpler, but more hacky.

Finally, if it's just a short amount of time, the service won't exit until all threads have died (unless they are background threads); so if it's a short amount of time, the service control manager won't mind a second or so - you can just leave them to expire - in my experience.

Comment: They should be short-lived, but for my use case, I need more assurance than "should work".  I'm thinking of using an interlocked thread counter to track the number of threads in the pool, and waiting on that equalling zero.

Comment: Actually, I like your first suggestion better than the counter.

Answer (score 3):

The standard pattern for doing this is to use a counter which holds the number of pending work items and one `ManualResetEvent` that is signalled when the counter reaches zero. This is generally better than using a `WaitHandle` for each work item as that does not scale very well when there are a lot of simultaneous work items. Plus, some of the static `WaitHandle` method only accept a maximum of 64 instances anyway.

```
// Initialize to 1 because we are going to treat the current thread as
// a work item as well. This is to avoid a race that could occur when
// one work item gets queued and completed before the next work item
// is queued.
int count = 1;
var finished = new ManualResetEvent(false); 
try 
{ 
  while (...)
  {  
    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( 
      delegate(object state) 
      { 
        try 
        { 
          // Your task goes here. 
        } 
        finally 
        { 
          // Decrement the counter to indicate the work item is done.
          if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0) 
          { 
            finished.Set(); 
          } 
        } 
      }); 
  } 
}
finally
{
  // Decrement the counter to indicate the queueing thread is done.
  if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0) 
  { 
    finished.Set(); 
  } 
}
finished.WaitOne();
```