# Console quits before threads complete (multithreading)

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, .net-3.5, threadpool

I have a console application and i use a threadpool, but my application exits before the threadpool execute its job. I read that i can use `Console.ReadLine()` but I want to exit immediately after threadpool done its job. I found examples in c# but i want something about vb.net, also i use .net 3.5 so i can't use task parallel library. My current code is:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To addresses.Length - 1
    Dim mydata_obj = New With {Key .address = addresses(i), .subject = messages.subject, .body = messages.body}
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf doSomething, mydata_obj)
Next
```

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426718/how-can-i-accomplish-threadpool-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` to wait it until task complete

for more information [WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Alternative is  using  `threadpool`

Waiting for an object can also be achieved using the threadpool. In some situations this is better because it means you don't need a dedicated thread to wait for the object.

ThreadPool class Provides a pool of threads that can be used to execute tasks, post work items, process asynchronous I/O, wait on behalf of other threads, and process timers.

Comment: thanks, what waitAll method takes as argument? Because i tried this and i gives me compile error..

Comment: @user1005633:ok,provided link in answer